# Appcelerator: Can't run or publish apps after Studio Update

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

I updated of Appcelerator Studio on Windows 10. During the process I got a message that there were errors during update process and Studio should be restarted.

Now I cannot run or publish apps (combo box is grey) and during every run Appcelerator Studio informs that there is an update to install: Appcelerator CLI core (required) with version N/A. If I try to install it I get following error:

```
Error encountered during update
undefined:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.readConfig (C:\Users\Worker\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v9.4.0\node_modules\appcelerator\lib\util.js:728:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Worker\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v9.4.0\node_modules\appcelerator\bin\appc:96:23)
at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
```

If I had problems with Appcelerator CLI core (required) with version N/A, I always used `appc setup` from command line and it was fixing the problem. But now if I type that I get same error.

I tried reinstalling Appcelerator, Node (I have updated version) but nothing helped.

Output of error when updating CLI via Studio:

```
STATUS
------
pluginId            com.appcelerator.titanium.core
pluginVersion       3.1.2.1512467051
code                0
severity            4
message             HIDDEN
fingerprint         [some_value_here]
stacktrace          

Exception:org.eclipse.epp.internal.logging.aeri.ui.log.StandInStacktraceProvider$StandInException: HIDDEN
 at com.aptana.core.logging.IdeLog.log(IdeLog.java:563)
 at com.aptana.core.logging.IdeLog.log(IdeLog.java:598)
 at com.aptana.core.logging.IdeLog.logError(IdeLog.java:306)
 at com.aptana.core.logging.IdeLog.logError(IdeLog.java:280)
 at com.aptana.core.logging.IdeLog.logError(IdeLog.java:258)
 at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.StudioVersionManager.getCLIActiveVersion(StudioVersionManager.java:139)
 at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.StudioVersionManager.isCurrentCLIVersionCompatibile(StudioVersionManager.java:78)
 at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.StudioVersionManager.isActiveCLICompatible(StudioVersionManager.java:49)
 at com.appcelerator.titanium.update.core.release.TitaniumStudioRelease.getUpdatesWithStableStream(TitaniumStudioRelease.java:219)
 at com.appcelerator.titanium.update.core.release.TitaniumStudioRelease.isInstalled(TitaniumStudioRelease.java:212)
 at com.appcelerator.titanium.update.internal.core.TitaniumReleasesUpdater$NotInstalledFilter.include(TitaniumReleasesUpdater.java:105)
 at com.appcelerator.titanium.update.internal.core.TitaniumReleasesUpdater$NotInstalledFilter.include(TitaniumReleasesUpdater.java:1)
 at com.aptana.core.util.AndFilter.include(AndFilter.java:39)
 at com.aptana.core.util.CollectionsUtil.filterInPlace(CollectionsUtil.java:249)
 at com.appcelerator.titanium.update.internal.core.TitaniumReleasesUpdater.filterToRelevantUninstalledUpdates(TitaniumReleasesUpdater.java:915)
 at com.appcelerator.titanium.update.internal.core.TitaniumReleasesUpdater.getStudioUpdates(TitaniumReleasesUpdater.java:326)
 at com.appcelerator.titanium.update.internal.core.TitaniumReleasesUpdater.getAvailableUpdates(TitaniumReleasesUpdater.java:314)
 at com.appcelerator.titanium.update.ui.handler.TitaniumUpdateHandler$1.run(TitaniumUpdateHandler.java:66)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

------
REPORT
------
name                [email_I_use_to_log_in]
email               anonymous
comment             
productVersion      5.0.0.201712081732
productName         Appcelerator Studio
javaRuntimeVersion  1.8.0_162-b12
osgiWs              win32
osgiOs              Windows 10
osgiOsVersion       10.0.0
osgiArch            x86
```

Output of `ti info` as requested:

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Microsoft Windows 10 Home
  Version                     = 10.0.16299
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 7.9GB

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 8.9.4 //I set to 8.9.4 but had same errors with 9.4.0
  npm Version                 = 5.6.0

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.14
  node-appc Version           = 0.2.41

Titanium SDKs
  7.0.0.GA
    Version                   = 7.0.0
    Install Location          = C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\7.0.0.GA
    Platforms                 = android, windows
    git Hash                  = f09dec4
    git Timestamp             = 12/5/2017 21:33
    node-appc Version         = 0.2.43
  6.2.2.GA
Version                   = 6.2.2
Install Location          = C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.2.2.GA
    Platforms                 = android, mobileweb, windows
    git Hash                  = 42c7196
    git Timestamp             = 9/19/2017 23:04
    node-appc Version         = 0.2.43

/****
Here is more SDKS
****/  

Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)
  Not installed

Java Development Kit
  Version                     = 1.8.0_162
  Java Home                   = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_162

Genymotion
  Path                        = C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion
  Genymotion Executable       = C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\genymotion.exe
  Genymotion Player           = C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\player.exe
  Home                        = C:\Users\Worker\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion

VirtualBox
  Executable                  = C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
  Version                     = 5.2.0r118431

Android SDK
  Android Executable          = not found
  ADB Executable              = C:\android-sdk-win\platform-tools\adb.exe
  SDK Path                    = C:\android-sdk-win

Android NDK
  NDK Path                    = not found
  NDK Version                 = not found

Android Platforms
  1) android-23
    Name                      = Android 6.0
    API Level                 = 23
    Revision                  = 3
    Skins                     = HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800, WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in, AndroidWearRound, AndroidWearRound360x360, AndroidWearRound400x400, AndroidWearRound480x480, AndroidWearRoundChin320x290, AndroidWearRoundChin320x300, AndroidWearRoundChin360x325, AndroidWearRoundChin360x326, AndroidWearRoundChin360x330, AndroidWearSquare, AndroidWearSquare240x240, AndroidWearSquare320x320
    ABIs                      = armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64
    Path                      = C:\android-sdk-win\platforms\android-23

 Android Add-Ons
  None

Android Emulators
  AVD_for_Nexus_6
    ID                        = AVD_for_Nexus_6
    SDK Version               = not installed
    ABI                       = armeabi-v7a
    Skin                      = 1440x2560
    Path                      = C:\Users\Worker\.android\avd\AVD_for_Nexus_6.avd
    SD Card                   = no sd card
    Google APIs               = no
  titanium_1_WVGA800
    ID                        = titanium_1_WVGA800
    SDK Version               = not installed
    ABI                       = armeabi-v7a
    Skin                      = wvga800
    Path                      = C:\Users\Worker\.android\avd\titanium_1_WVGA800.avd
    SD Card                   = C:\Users\Worker\.android\avd\titanium_1_WVGA800.avd\sdcard.img
    Google APIs               = no

/****
Here is the list Genymotion Emulators
****/

Connected Android Devices
  None

Microsoft (R) Visual Studio
  14.0 (selected)
    Path                      = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\
    CLR Version               = v4.0.30319
    MSBuild Version           = vnull
    Windows Phone SDKs        = not installed

Microsoft (R) Windows Phone SDK
  No versions found

Windows PowerShell
    Enabled                   = yes

Windows Phone Emulators
10.0

Windows Phone Devices

Android Issues
  !  Unable to locate an Android NDK.
     Without the NDK, you will not be able to build native Android Titanium modules.
     If you have already downloaded and installed the Android NDK, you can tell Titanium where the
     Android NDK is located by running 'titanium config android.ndkPath /path/to/android-ndk',
     otherwise you can install it by running 'titanium setup android' or manually downloading from
     http://appcelerator.com/android-ndk.

  !
     Android Build Tools 27.0.0 are too new and may or may not work with Titanium.
     If you encounter problems, select a supported version with:
        ti config android.buildTools.selectedVersion ##.##.##
      where ##.##.## is a version in  that is 26.x

Windows Issues
  ×  Microsoft Windows Phone SDK not found.
     You will be unable to build Windows Phone apps.
     You can install it from http://appcelerator.com/windowsphone.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Does `ti info` still work? What did you do to try to update appc? `npm install -g appcelerator titanium alloy`? If not try that please

Comment: @miga: Thanks for the answer but it didn't help. I was updating Appcelerator in normal way (from Studio). In past if there were any errors with Appcelerator CLI core with version N/A, then typing appc setup in Command Line was solving situation.
`ti info` was showing that `ti is not recognized command` but after `npm install -g appcelerator titatnium alloy` the `ti info` is working and showing no errors. It had no effect on the issue I have - still getting same error

Comment: please show the output of `ti info` since it will give some more details about the versions you have installed

Comment: @miga: I udated post with ti info output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the issue.

Instructions:

1. Uninstall Appcelerator Studio.
2. Remove directories with settings:

   `.android
   .appcelerator
   .titanium`
3. Unistall npm modules:

   `npm uninstall -g titanium
    npm uninstall -g alloy
    npm uninstall -g acs
    npm uninstall -g appcelerator`
4. Reinstall Appcelerator Studio.
5. If still have problems: Close Appcelerator Studio, type `appc setup` and restart Appcelerator Studio.